# Getting an error with reading a CSV file with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I was trying to do some analysis using pandas and experiencing error with `pd.read_csv` command, below is the error, please help why am I getting this when I had imported and used it right,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Case1.csv')
```

Error is:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1133, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2037, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 860, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 875, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 929, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 916, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2071, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 4
```

Comment: Can you show a printscreen of csv and what type of csv it is?

Comment: "Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 4" looks like an good error message to me. I would investigate that by inspecting the CSV file.

Comment: try putting your python file and csv file in same folder

Comment: @SamarthMotka They are in the same folder

Comment: [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) guesses that your file has 3 columns based on the first line of the csv. However, there exists at least one line where 4 colums (i.e. 3 column delimiters) are present.

Comment: As stated in Pandas documentation for read.csv() method, you could choose to skip the faulty row by setting `on_bad_lines` parameter to `skip`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69924444/11246056